# Add Group ID to After Each Cycle in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table looks like this

| name | event_time | event_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2020-01-01 | run |
| a | 2020-01-03 | run |
| a | 2020-01-05 | end |
| a | 2020-01-18 | run |
| a | 2020-01-29 | end |
| b | 2020-02-12 | run |
| b | 2020-03-01 | end |

I want to create a group ID (or some group name) to group together every run-end cycle for each name so that table above could look like this:

| name | event_time | event_type | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2020-01-01 | run | 1 |
| a | 2020-01-03 | run | 1 |
| a | 2020-01-05 | end | 1 |
| a | 2020-01-18 | run | 2 |
| a | 2020-01-29 | end | 2 |
| b | 2020-02-12 | run | 3 |
| b | 2020-03-01 | end | 3 |

I tried row_number() and also used row_number partition to subtract from each other, but it doesn't really give me what I want.

Comment: I am using redshift. adding postgresql as I thought redshift is based on postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count the event_type = 'end' up to the previous row:

```
select count(case when event_type = 'end' then 1 end) 
         over (order by event_time
               rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) + 1 as group_id
from mytable
order by event_time;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . you seem to what a cumulative sum of `'end'`s -- but in reverse order.  That would then give you the numbering in reverse order, so you can use some subtraction.

The idea is:

```
select t.*,
       (1 + sum( (event_type = 'end')::int ) over () -
        sum( (event_type = 'end')::int ) over (order by event_time desc)
       ) as group_id
from t
order by event_time;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a4605edb4d2fe6f4e416a7e15e8ac423) is a db<>fiddle.